# Webcam recording with FFmpeg through USB over UTP

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to record my webcam with FFmpeg.

I listed the devices with this line:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

And I test the settings with this one:

```
ffplay -loglevel verbose -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 60 -video_device_number 0 -audio_device_number 0 -i video="C922 Pro Stream Webcam":audio="Microphone (C922 Pro Stream Web"
```

The first command outputs this:

```
ffmpeg version n4.4-10-g75c3969292 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10-win32 (GCC) 20210408
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[dshow @ 000000000035a000] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 000000000035a000]  "C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
[dshow @ 000000000035a000]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_046d&pid_085c&mi_00#9&1da24ac&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 000000000035a000] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 000000000035a000]  "Microphone (C922 Pro Stream Web"
[dshow @ 000000000035a000]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Microphone (C922 Pro Stream Web"
[dshow @ 000000000035a000]  "Microphone (Realtek High Defini"
[dshow @ 000000000035a000]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Microphone (Realtek High Defini"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

And the second one this:

```
ffplay version n4.4-10-g75c3969292 Copyright (c) 2003-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10-win32 (GCC) 20210408
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Initialized direct3d renderer.
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
dshow passing through packet of type video size   170103 timestamp 2074640340000 orig timestamp 2074640336004 graph timestamp 2074640340000 diff 3996 C922 Pro Stream Webcam
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
dshow passing through packet of type video size   166381 timestamp 2074640500000 orig timestamp 2074640502670 graph timestamp 2074640500000 diff -2670 C922 Pro Stream Webcam
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
dshow passing through packet of type video size   173348 timestamp 2074640820000 orig timestamp 2074640816017 graph timestamp 2074640820000 diff 3983 C922 Pro Stream Webcam
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
...
```

However, if I use a USB cable extender (USB over UTP - This thing consist of two parts: the first one has a male, the second one a female USB A, and they are linked through RJ45 sockets and a Cat5e UTP cable), it does not work at all. The first command prints the same:

```
ffmpeg version n4.4-10-g75c3969292 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10-win32 (GCC) 20210408
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[dshow @ 000000000039a000] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 000000000039a000]  "C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
[dshow @ 000000000039a000]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_046d&pid_085c&mi_00#9&1da24ac&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 000000000039a000] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 000000000039a000]  "Microphone (C922 Pro Stream Web"
[dshow @ 000000000039a000]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Microphone (C922 Pro Stream Web"
[dshow @ 000000000039a000]  "Microphone (Realtek High Defini"
[dshow @ 000000000039a000]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Microphone (Realtek High Defini"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

But the second fails with "Could not set video options":

```
ffplay version n4.4-10-g75c3969292 Copyright (c) 2003-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10-win32 (GCC) 20210408
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --enable-vulkan --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Initialized direct3d renderer.
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   

[dshow @ 00000000004de180] Could not set video options
video=C922 Pro Stream Webcam:audio=Microphone (C922 Pro Stream Web: I/O error
```

What can be the problem? Is it the extender cable? What are FFmpeg's requirement on USB cables (and extenders)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a software/configuration issue - it's purely electrical one. I assume you have passive USB over Ethernet adapters which only convert the wiring without touching signal itself. 5-10 meters is realistic maximum you can expect from that kind of cable (I tested for myself using iPhone and Mac Mini).

Active USB over Ethernet adapters might help. They work in entirely different way and they are completely transparent to both host and guest device - no additional configuration needed.

For details about limitations of USB cables see this answer https://superuser.com/a/64747/416084

Comment: And how can I distinguish active USB over Ethernet from passive? I read the description of many products and neither says active or passive.

Comment: Active in most cases require additional power supply (5V from USB is not enough).